# Keypad Combinations Phone number

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

I know this question has been asked a hundred times but I am looking for a solution that does not involve any String functions or external classes.

I have written a few classes that actually work but they all use String.substring or String.replace, Arraylists etc. which is not allowed in my situation.

I have been on this for more than a week now and I can't seem to get any progress.

I just can't put String methods in a very big loop or something.

Any ideas?

Here is what I have written up until now.

```
public class Oldie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] array = {
            { '0' }, { '1' }, { 'A', 'B', 'C' }, { 'D', 'E', 'F' },
            { 'G', 'H', 'I' }, { 'J', 'K', 'L' }, { 'M', 'N', 'O' },
            { 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S' }, { 'T', 'U', 'V' }, { 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' }
        };

        String num = "222";
        int[] number = new int[num.length()];
        char[] permutations = new char[num.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            number[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
        }

        char First, Second, Third;

        for (char i = array[number[0]][0]; i <= array[number[0]][array[number[0]].length - 1]; i++) {
            First = i;

            for (char j = array[number[1]][0]; j <= array[number[1]][array[number[1]].length - 1]; j++) {
                Second = j;

                for (char k = array[number[2]][0]; k <= array[number[2]][array[number[2]].length - 1]; k++) {
                    Third = k;

                    System.out.println("" + First + "" + Second + "" + Third);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be better if I could do it in a base type solution with redix etc.

Comment: The solution above is just for 3 digits, which is not good as well. I want to make it dynamic so it is not limited to phone number's length.

Comment: Can you please explain, what your code should do?

Comment: It should give out all the combinations possible for a given number. I.e. 111-532-532 has the following 111-KFC-KFC and 111-LFC-LFC

Comment: Why do people begin their questions with _I know this question has been asked a hundred times..._?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi to avoid some people telling me its a duplicate of blah blah - sometimes the already answered questions are not what we are trying to do, but some people would just never understand - look the comment above yours for a practical example.

Comment: Well, but it **is** an **exact** duplicate. And Oh the Irony! That question's score is 0, while this has 1. -_-.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Apologies, but all the answers I had gotten in other posts used string methods/arraylists which are a little heavier in regards to what I was trying to do. The answers I've gotten here have very little usage of String methods and/or arraylists, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure, what you mean with your loops, but when you fix it, this should be another solution without saving the String (right now this throws an "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" since i dont right understand, what you want to accomplish with your for-loops). This code should be more considered as an hint how to solve your problem and not the full solution! This also kind of saves old Strings. Instead you could also delete the last char of the String at the end of each for-loop:

```
public class Oldie {
    char[][] array = {
            { '0' }, { '1' }, { 'A', 'B', 'C' }, { 'D', 'E', 'F' },
            { 'G', 'H', 'I' }, { 'J', 'K', 'L' }, { 'M', 'N', 'O' },
            { 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S' }, { 'T', 'U', 'V' }, { 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' }
        };
    String num = "222";
    String savedPerm;
    int[] number = new int[num.length()];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Oldie oldie = new Oldie();
        oldie.givePerm(0);
    }

    Oldie(){
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            number[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    private void givePerm(int position){
        String oldSavedPerm=savedPerm;
//      if(array.length!=number.length){
//          System.out.println("Different length!");
//          System.out.println(array.length+";"+number.length);
//          return;
//      }
        for (char c = array[number[position]][0]; c <= array[number[position]][array[number[position]].length - 1]; c++) {
            savedPerm=c+oldSavedPerm;
            if(position<array.length-1)
                givePerm(position+1);
            else
                System.out.println(savedPerm);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My aplogies for not being as clear - let me put some clarity on what I want to acheive

I want to create a program that would give me all the possible combinations for a digit with respect to the conventional phone keypad, for example the number 2 has abc written on it, number 3 has "def"

so the number "23" should have 

AD
AE
AF
BD
BE
BF
CD
CE
CF

I'm now copying your solution to my class to see how can it help :) btw thanks for all this help. really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks!! it works!! wow!
I will post the changes I made in a different answer so others can see the final code :)

I made a few changes to make it work - THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach on your problem.

```
char[][] array = {
    { '0' }, { '1' }, { 'A', 'B', 'C' }, { 'D', 'E', 'F' },
    { 'G', 'H', 'I' }, { 'J', 'K', 'L' }, { 'M', 'N', 'O' },
    { 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S' }, { 'T', 'U', 'V' }, { 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' }
};
String num = "123";

// creates an combination Array
// for 123 this is {{1},{ABC},{DEF}}
char[][] combinationArr = new char[num.length()][];         
for(int ix = 0; ix < num.length(); ix++)
    combinationArr[ix] = array[Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(ix))];

// now print all permutations of combination Array
// ics holds the actual index at each position
int[] ics = new int[num.length()];
boolean end = false;
while(!end){ // while there are combinations left       
    // print the actual combination
    for(int i = 0; i < combinationArr.length; i++)
        System.out.print(combinationArr[i][ics[i]]);
    System.out.println();               
    // increases one index, starting with the last one.
    // If there is no char left it starts again at 0
    // and the index before will get increased.
    // If the first one could not get increased
    // we have all combinations.
    for(int i = ics.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        ics[i]++;
        if(ics[i] == combinationArr[i].length)
            if(i == 0) end = true;
            else ics[i] = 0;
        else break;
    }               
}
```

Comment: Yet another great and efficient approach to this problem! This is awesome!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what actually worked for me!! Thanks to ctst!

```
public class Oldie {
private static char[][] array = { { '0' }, { '1' }, { 'A', 'B', 'C' }, { 'D', 'E', 'F' },
        { 'G', 'H', 'I' }, { 'J', 'K', 'L' }, { 'M', 'N', 'O' },
        { 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S' }, { 'T', 'U', 'V' }, { 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' } };
private static String num = "2222";
private static char[] savedPerm = new char[num.length];
private static int[] number = new int[num.length()];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        number[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
    }
    givePerm(0);
}


private static void givePerm(int position) {
    for (char c = array[number[position]][0]; c <= array[number[position]][array[number[position]].length - 1]; c++) {
        savedPerm[position] = c;
        if (position < number.length - 1)
            givePerm(position + 1);
        else{
            for(char text: savedPerm){
                 System.out.print(""+text);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me how do i use the above code and avoid creating strings? I just need to print and it would really optimize it if there were no strings

Comment: I edited you answer to match your request (just change `savedPerm` from `String` to `char[]` with length of `num` and change `savedPerm[position]=c;`

Comment: WOW! It is EXACTLY what I was looking for!! Thanks man! you rock!!

Comment: I'm not sure who on earth down voted this answer, I already am short of reputation as I am new! :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a recursive method:

```
private String givePerm(String givenPerm, char[][] array, int position, int[] number){
    if(array.length!=number.length)
        return null;
    for (char c = array[number[position]][0]; c <= array[number[position]][array[number[position]].length - 1]; c++) {
        String permString;
        if(position<array.length-1)
             permString = givePerm(c+givenPerm, array, position+1);
        else
             permString = ""+c; 
        return permString;
     }
}
```

Comment: Need to declare `i` also.

Comment: ah, thats the pitty with copy pasting... i fix it. Feel free to edit. Hopefully now the bugs should be fixed. Thx for the feedback.

Comment: The issue with this is that it is using string functions and lists which make the program a little heavier. It's not actually something I am doing for a project or something but kind of a task, where I would need to code according to what I am told :)

Comment: What about adding the chars to a String and in the last call of this methods print this String. Then you wouldnt have to take the String to every method (btw. you can make array and number class fields, which would eliminate that parameter). I will write another answer.

Comment: I just need to print all the combinations so there is no need to actually store them in any array

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion, you can call the `permutations` method and keep on reducing the the number of input digits, by grabbing the head digit and passing the tail into the next call.

```
public class Oldie {
    private static final char[][] KEYS = {
        { '0' },
        { '1' },             { 'A','B','C' }, { 'D','E','F' },
        { 'G','H','I' },     { 'J','K','L' }, { 'M','N','O' },
        { 'P','Q','R','S' }, { 'T','U','V' }, { 'W','X','Y','Z' }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            permutations("222");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void permutations(String inputNumber) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        permutations(toDigitArray(inputNumber), "");
    }

    private static void permutations(int[] inputDigits, String outputLetters) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int headDigit = inputDigits[0];
        int[] tailDigits = tail(inputDigits);
        char[] letters = KEYS[headDigit];

        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            char letter = letters[i];
            String result = outputLetters + letter;

            if (tailDigits.length == 0) {
                System.out.println(result);
            } else {
                permutations(tailDigits, result);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] toDigitArray(String str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return toDigitArray(str.toCharArray());
    }

    private static int[] toDigitArray(char[] arr) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int[] intArr = new int[arr.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character is not a valid digit");
            }

            intArr[i] = Character.digit(arr[i], 10);
        }

        return intArr;
    }

    private static int[] tail(int[] arr) {
        int[] dest = new int[arr.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 1, dest, 0, dest.length);
        return dest;
    }
}
```

---

#### Output

```
AAA
AAB
AAC
ABA
ABB
ABC
ACA
ACB
ACC
BAA
BAB
BAC
BBA
BBB
BBC
BCA
BCB
BCC
CAA
CAB
CAC
CBA
CBB
CBC
CCA
CCB
CCC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) please look at the answer i wrote - I think that one is more fast